# Angular $watch a service object from a controller and read properties

Tags: angularjs, object, service, controller, watch

I've been trying to watch a service object from a controller. I've been trying to solve this problem in a nice way but it has been imposible. the only solution I could find is this one (see the code). The thing is when I "console.log" the returned value, I can see the object but I can not access to the properties. it says "undefined". So the only solution I could find is this one but I don't like it too much. Any ideas???

This is my "watcher" of my controller:

```
$scope.$watchCollection(function(){return angular.toJson(measuresServ.getFinalMeasuresVal())},function(newVal, oldVal) {
    $scope.measures = JSON.parse(newVal);
    console.log($scope.measures);
    console.log($scope.measures.temperatura);
});
```

This is the object of my service:

```
var finalMeasures = {};

return {
    getMeasures : function(){
        finalMeasures.temperatura = 24;
        finalMeasures.humedad = 45;
    },
    getMeasuresVal: function(){
        return finalMeasures;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should work:

```
$scope.$watch(function () { 
    return measuresServ.getFinalMeasuresVal();
}, function (newVal, oldVal) {
    console.log(newVal);
}, true);
```

Comment: That way you can just watch individual properties. When you are trying to watch an object you must use "$watchCollection", otherwise when some of the properties change, you don't notice the changes. The problem is that I can not access to the properties of the object once is returned. If you try to do "newVal.temperatura" it returns undefined. Is why I had to returned as a JSON string and parse it. But to me is pretty ugly. I would like to do it in a direct way.